# Have a bond with someone

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning, idioms, expressions

An American native speaker wrote me:

> When I play the PlayStation games, I feel like I **have a bond with** the player in the game.

[Bond:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bond)

- a close connection joining two or more people.

I wonder whether "have a bond with the player" means: "I have sense of (psychological) identification" here or something different?

**Identification (psychology-wise):**

- Identification is a psychological process whereby the individual assimilates an aspect, property, or attribute of the other and is transformed wholly or partially by the model that other provides.

If it does not, then please let me know what did he mean by using that expression?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dictionary definition "A close connection" is right.

The psychological term "identification" is not relevant.

"I have a bond with the player" means "I feel connected to them". It does not mean "I assimilate aspects, properties or attributes of the other."

Comment: I am wondering how he can feel connected to the player here @James K?

Comment: Do you have any friends?  I feel a connection with my friends, without psychological identification with them.

Comment: But this goes beyond the meaning of the word in English.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your interpretation is right.
*bond* takes this meaning in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bond).

> bond noun (CONNECTION)

> a close connection joining two or more people:
> the bond(s) of friendship/love